# USDT on Sepolia

Tags: erc-20, metamask, testnets, usdt, sepolia

I'm currently working on testing ERC-20 transactions on the Sepolia testnet and I'm looking to obtain some USDT for this purpose. Could anyone guide me on how to acquire USDT on Sepolia? I've been managing my ETH through MetaMask, but I'm not sure how to go about adding USDT to my test wallet.

Comment: Maybe trade in uniswap?

Comment: Thanks, I've tried several contract addresses but found no liquidity for USDT swaps on Sepolia. Do you know any that work? @LauriPeltonen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the two USDT token contracts I found on sepolia testnet, [USDT1](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xaa8e23fb1079ea71e0a56f48a2aa51851d8433d0) [USDT2](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x7169d38820dfd117c3fa1f22a697dba58d90ba06#writeContract). You can check either of these.

On the other hand you can also deploy by your side for testing.

Comment: Thank you so much (:

Comment: May I ask how you found such contracts? Is there any special way to find them, or did you find them randomly? I’d love to know for future reference.

Comment: I just googled "USDT on sepolia".

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do. Most of the time, the best option is to create your ERC20 contract on Sepolia and consider tokens as USDT.

In that way, you will be able to get as much as you want.

Comment: I'm looking to test my code for transferring USDT on the ERC-20 network using the Sepolia testnet.